# Display Inline CSS property behavior. Can somebody explain?

Tags: html, css

I have used three div's with css styling as display inline block with some specific width and height. The Div which as some text is pushing down. Can anybody tell me what could be the reason ? below is the code

Html:

```
<div></div>
<div>why this pushed down?</div>
<div></div>
```

Css :

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P5HGJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element behaves like a block element, but it remains inline.

You can change the vertical alignment with vertical-align: middle.

```
.show-inline{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/7y7Hd/1/

Read about vertical-align at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Meh took too much time typing my answer ^^ This the right answer yea.

Comment: Mark Simpson & Nkmol - Thanks to both of you guys :) for helping me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the [baseline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)). Whenever you use an `inline-block` the baseline is calculated on the `line-height` of the font.

Because the outer `<div>`s don't have any font the baseline will *not* have the same calculation/position as the one with the font.

You can simply fix this by giving a global baseline on all the `<divs>`:

```
div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    height:150px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f00;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It doesn't really matter if you use `top`, `middle`, or `bottom`. As long as the baseline is on all the `<div>`s the same, it should be no problem

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P5HGJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

inline-block makes the element generate a block box that’s laid out as 
   if it were an inline box.

inline block is placed inline (ie. on the same line as adjacent content),
  but it behaves as a block.